# Microsoft edge browser crashes the JS engine on regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex, microsoft-edge

I found a way to mysteriously crash the edge JS interpreter but i have NO CLUE why it's broke. It works fine in firefox and chrome, but it blows up Edge entirely.

```
var foo = "Change or cancel my flight booking";
var match = "a";
foo.replace(new RegExp(match + "(?!([^<]+)?>)", 'gu'), '<span class="text-highlight">${match}</span>');
```

The problem seems to be with the regex itself because if i swap that for empty string all goes well.

Really not sure how trying to match a regex could destroy the browser :(

Edit: For clarity, when executed via html in the browser, it goes into a non-responsive state. Nothing can be clicked and eventually edge asks if you want to close the page because its nonresponsive. When executed in the dev console, it doesn't print a return, and any further statements are never executed. You can keep typing, but nothing happens.

Comment: Based on what you described, this is most likely a bug in Edge. You might want to let them know on the [Microsoft Edge issue tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what happens with the crash? E.g. Does the browser hang? Does the browser exit completely? Any error messages?

Comment: I'll update the question with elaboration.

Comment: apparently ... "This browser does not have lookbehind support" and "This browser does not have named group support" - according to https://regex101.com/r/Wvixo3/1/ - so regex101 doesn't even try.

Comment: @JaromandaX When i run your link in edge it gives a timeout message :(

Comment: really? I just get those messages in the console, then I assume the regex is not even attempted

Answer (score 3):

If I run the regex without the `u` Unicode flag no timeout or crash happens in Edge (or any other major browser):

```js
var foo = "Change or cancel my flight booking";
var match = "a";
console.log(foo.replace(new RegExp(match + "(?!([^<]+)?>)", 'g'), '<span class="text-highlight">${match}</span>'));
```

The ES2015 `u` flag for regular expressions is actually associated with a number of [bugs](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex#support) on different browsers, e.g. the HTML pattern attribute is [broken in Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7113940/).

So, this issue seems to be a similar but different bug related to the `u` flag and should be reported on the [Microsoft Edge issue tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/).

Comment: I'll be reporting to them today. Unfortunatly i need to run the regex over unicode strings so.... Kinda stuck.

Comment: Anything written in a regex can also be implemented with string parsing code. E.g. for loop, read one char at a time, update parsing state. It's more work, of course. But you said you were stuck, so I thought I'd suggest it.